# Reactjs Javascript How to get window variables into react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been following the other post on how to get variables from javascript to reactjs.

I have my array of objects like the follows in Javascript

```
window.dataArr = [];

function makeJsObj(descr, currDate, done) {
        var data = {};
        console.log(descr + " " + currDate + " " + done);
        data['desc'] = descr;
        data['targetDate'] = currDate;
        data['done'] = done;
        dataArr.push(data);
    }
```

In react this is how I call the above array

```
<App items={window.dataArr}/>
<TodoList items={items} />
```

and

```
function TodoList({ items }) {
  return items.map(item => (
      <h1>{item.desc}</h1>
  ));
}
```

I am getting an error that I am using map on undefined

Runnable Snippet

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App({items}) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>

      <TodoList items={items} />
    </div>


  );
}
function TodoList({ items }) {
  return items.map(item => (
      <h1>{item.desc}</h1>
  ));
}
export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
ReactDOM.render(<App items={window.dataArr}/>, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable snippet to illustrate your problem.

Comment: I would guess that `items` is undefined in `<TodoList items={items} />`. Did you mean to reference the `App` property or just use `window.dataArr` again?

Comment: I have updated my OP. Please let me know why did I get a negative vote

Comment: It's unknown at which point `window.dataArr = []` is executed. That you have this problem suggests that it's not executed at all or executed after React script. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Comment: Where do you call `makeJsObj`?

Comment: Makejsonobj method is in plain javascript

Comment: @estus in TodoList the items gets passed from App

Comment: I see that. The only possibility for it to not be an array is that window.dataArr in `<App items={window.dataArr}/>` is not defined. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: @estus If you could kindly use my reactjs snippets and javascript code and run. I have come home for the weekend

Comment: In case `window.dataArr = []` runs before `ReactDOM.render(<App items={window.dataArr}/>`, it should work. Otherwise it won't. I'd assume that's the problem here because snippets themselves seem to be ok.

Comment: @estus Actually I am getting values from the server. Infact I did call and make the js array before but it didnt pick the values. Thanks for looking into it

Comment: *I did call and make the js array* - this likely means that there's race condition and a response arrives later than `window.dataArr` is used by React. Any way, the problem is specific to how React and non-React parts interact.

Comment: @estus ok thanks. I will change my approach. Can we get some inspiration from here https://codepen.io/Dinir/pen/YqMJLL

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)?

```
state = {
  dataArr: []
}

<App items={this.state.dataArr}/>
<TodoList items={this.state.dataArr} />
```

Suggested reading: [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: dataArr is in plain javascript.  I am trying to access that array in reactjs. Can you please help

Comment: require that file and use in the state.

Comment: Ok i will try it. See the actual scenario is that I am getting values from the server into js. So i cannot require it. That is embedded javascript.